# Webform email themeing

Tags: theming, webforms, emails

How do I theme emails sent via a Webform to display like the webform preview?

Below is the output from the email, viewed in Gmail and below that is the output from the preview of the form.

I am using Drupal Version 8.4.3
Webform Version: 8.x-5.0-rc1, with all modules enabled.
Mail System: Version: 8.x-4.1.
Other modules include:
Ctools
Pathauto
Token
Twig tweak
Honeypot
Imce File Manager

This is the output of the email from Gmail

[image: Gmail output]

And this the preview of the message in the form.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The styling of an element is handled via the [webform-element-base-html.html.twig](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/templates/webform-element-base-html.html.twig) template. The email formatting is using simple HTML markup vs Drupal's standard [form element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21form-element.html.twig/8.5.x)/item output.

If you globally want the layout of all elements to be on a single line in email. You should change...

```
{% if title %}<b>{{ title }}</b><br />{% endif %}{{ value }}<br /><br />
```

to

```
{% if title %}<b>{{ title }}</b> {% endif %}{{ value }}<br /><br />
```

Comment: Thanks. Editing the webform-element-base-html.html.twig template got the layout as required with the elements.  I would like to know where to add/insert css or yaml code to format elements to display the email like the preview.